# How to use form submit when using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i test the below code but does not work.

```
$("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form)
{
    alert('submit');
    //form.submit();
    return false;
};
```

where i made the mistake any idea.

i am getting this error at ***firbug*** **TypeError: $(...).data(...)** is undefined

looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: Have you referenced jQuery?

Comment: yes i refer all the required js file but still no luck.

Comment: do you need to call submit handler when the form is validated and not having any errors ?

Comment: when i run the page then firbug show this error: TypeError: $(...).data(...)