# How to perform conditional client side validation by jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

here i am giving my html. i have a dropdown which showing few product info and showing hobbies by checkbox. i want if user select product **iPod** then validation will not fire for hobbies checkboxes other wise fire. how to perform this kind of conditional validation by jquery validate plugin adding jquery rules.

```
<form name="TestVal" method="post" action="/" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateValTest</h4>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="padding-top: 0px;" for="Products" class="control-label col-md-2">Products</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="SelectedProductId" id="SelectedProductId" data-val-required="Select any Product" data-val-number="The field SelectedProductId must be a number." data-val="true">
                    <option value="">-- Select Product--</option>
                    <option value="1">IPhone</option>
                    <option value="2">MacBook Pro</option>
                    <option value="3">iPod</option>
                </select>
                <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="SelectedProductId" class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 input-validation-error">
                <b>Hobbies</b><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[0].IsSelected" id="Hobbies" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." data-val="true" class="hobbycls"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[0].IsSelected">
                &nbsp; 
                <label for="Hobbies_0__IsSelected">Reading</label>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" value="Reading" name="Hobbies[0].Name" id="Hobbies_0__Name"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[1].IsSelected" id="Hobbies" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." data-val="true" class="hobbycls"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[1].IsSelected">
                &nbsp; 
                <label for="Hobbies_1__IsSelected">Sports</label>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" value="Sports" name="Hobbies[1].Name" id="Hobbies_1__Name"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[2].IsSelected" id="Hobbies" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." data-val="true" class="hobbycls"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[2].IsSelected">
                &nbsp; 
                <label for="Hobbies_2__IsSelected">Movies</label>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" value="Movies" name="Hobbies[2].Name" id="Hobbies_2__Name">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### Right now i am doing client side validation by this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var declarationsError = $('#Hobbies-error');
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($("#SelectedProductId option:selected").text() != 'iPod') {
            if ($(".hobbycls:checkbox:checked").length <= 0) {
                declarationsError.empty();
                declarationsError.append("<span>Select Any Hobbie's checkbox</span>");
                declarationsError.show();
                return false;
            } else {
                declarationsError.empty();
                declarationsError.hide();
            }
        }

        declarationsError.hide();
        return true;
    });

    $('.hobbycls').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            declarationsError.empty();
            declarationsError.hide(); // hide error message
        }
    });
</script>
```

the above script is working fine but i want to do the same using jquery validate plugin adding rules.

so please guide me what jquery validate code i need to write to perform the same. show me how to do this kind of conditional validation by adding jquery rules. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in the produced HTML:

1. same ID for different elements (i.e.: Hobbies)
2. labels linked to no element: i.e.: label  for="Products"

You may use the jQuery validator to add a new rule to repeat exactly what you do in your two jQuery functions:

1. $('form').submit(function () {
2. $('.hobbycls').change(function () {

You forgot to give the Hobbies-error element, so I used a div.

In the following the snippet:

```js
var validator;

// a new rule is required to test if iPod is selected and checkboxes are...
$.validator.addMethod('checkboxMaxIfiPodNotSelected', function (value, elem, param) {
  var selectedOptionVal = $(param.selEleiSiPod).val().trim();
  var selectedOptionText = $(param.selEleiSiPod).text().trim();
  if (selectedOptionText != 'iPod') {
    if (selectedOptionVal.length > 0) {
      if ($(':checkbox.' + elem.classList[0] + ":checked").length <= param.max) {
        $('#Hobbies-error').empty().append("<span>Select Any Hobbie's checkbox</span>").show();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      $('#Hobbies-error').empty().append("<span>Select a Product</span>").show();
      return false;
    }
  }
  $('#Hobbies-error').empty().hide();
  return true;
});

$(function () {
  // build the dynamic rules....
  var myRules = {};
  var myMessages = {};
  $(':checkbox.hobbycls').each(function (index, element) {
    myRules[element.name] = {
      checkboxMaxIfiPodNotSelected: {
        max: 0,
        selEleiSiPod: '#SelectedProductId option:selected'
      }
    };
    myMessages[element.name] = {
      checkboxMaxIfiPodNotSelected: function(params, element) {
        // it's not usefull to return a true error message because I used a div
        // but this is up to you how to manage and place the errors
        return '';
      }
    };
  });

  // use the rules and messages with validator...
  validator = $('form').validate({
    rules: myRules,
    messages: myMessages,
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
      alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form name="TestVal" method="post" action="/" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateValTest</h4>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="padding-top: 0px;" for="SelectedProductId" class="control-label col-md-2">Products</label>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="SelectedProductId" id="SelectedProductId"
                        data-val-required="Select any Product"
                        data-val-number="The field SelectedProductId must be a number." data-val="true">
                    <option value="">-- Select Product--</option>
                    <option value="1">IPhone</option>
                    <option value="2">MacBook Pro</option>
                    <option value="3">iPod</option>
                </select>
                <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="SelectedProductId"
                      class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 input-validation-error">
                <b>Hobbies</b><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[0].IsSelected" id="Hobbies"
                       data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." data-val="true" class="hobbycls"><input
                    type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[0].IsSelected">
                &nbsp;
                <label for="Hobbies_0__Name">Reading</label>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" value="Reading" name="Hobbies[0].Name" id="Hobbies_0__Name">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[1].IsSelected" id="Hobbies1"
                       data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required."
                       data-val="true" class="hobbycls">
                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[1].IsSelected">
                &nbsp;
                <label for="Hobbies_1__Name">Sports</label>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" value="Sports" name="Hobbies[1].Name" id="Hobbies_1__Name">
                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[2].IsSelected" id="Hobbies2"
                       data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required."
                       data-val="true" class="hobbycls">
                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[2].IsSelected">
                &nbsp;
                <label for="Hobbies_2__Name">Movies</label>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" value="Movies" name="Hobbies[2].Name" id="Hobbies_2__Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Hobbies-error" class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: when i select any product from product dropdown other than ipod then user has to select one hobbies check box but i test your code and notice no error message shown. can you provide js fiddle version of your rectified code. this time code is not working.

Comment: will it be possible to have a look at few post which got no answer. here is the 3 url. please check the url and contribute if possible.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306822/how-to-use-form-submit-when-using-jquery-unobtrusive-validation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306563/asp-net-mvc-how-to-supress-jquery-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-message-ba

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287583/asp-net-mvc-custom-client-side-validation-not-firing

Comment: @Mou Hi, just now I finished to take a look to your next questions. I apologize but in this moment I'm studying js, angularjs, reactjs, bootstrap,... on MVA and on books. I stopped with the server side for the moment. I followed, this weekend, my last MVA course  on js for advanced users (very interesting). Sorry, but I cannot and I do not have time to solve your problem. I hope you forgive me. I'm too much interested on client side. Bye.